# Xml Serializer on AWS Lambda using C# results in method not found exception

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use the xml serializer in AWS Lambda running c#.  I keep getting the following error when ran on AWS Lambda:

```
{
    "Message": "There is an error in XML document (0, 0).",
    "Data": {},
    "InnerException": {
        "Message": "Method not found: 'System.Xml.XmlReader System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.get_Reader()'.",
        "Data": {},
        "InnerException": null,
        "StackTrace": "   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderDataSetHandleParam.InitIDs()\n   at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.InvokeReader(XmlMapping mapping, XmlReader xmlReader, Object events, String encodingStyle)\n   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, Object events)",
        "HelpLink": null,
        "Source": "Microsoft.GeneratedCode",
        "HResult": -2146233069
    },
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, Object events)\n   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)\n   at erp.client.agility.Models.Soap.Inventory.GetItemsResponse.Load(XmlNode node)\n   at erp.client.agility.AgilityErpCommunicator.Send[TK,T](String url, HttpMethod method, TK content)\n   at erp.client.agility.AgilityErpCommunicator.GetInventoryForProduct(String sessionContextId, String itemCode)\n   at erp.Repository.impl.Agility.AgilityRepository.GetInventoryForProduct(List`1 itemCodes)\n   at erp.Handler.InventoryForProduct(Request request, ILambdaContext context)",
    "HelpLink": null,
    "Source": "System.Xml.XmlSerializer",
    "HResult": -2146233079
}
```

Here's the calling code:

```
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataSetHandleParam));
        this.ItemDatasetHandle = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as DataSetHandleParam;
```

When I run it locally (Windows 10), I'm not getting the error.

From package.json:

```
"System.Xml.XmlSerializer": "4.3.0"
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Edit:  I opened up a support ticket with AWS.  It is a bug--they're looking into it.

Comment: Are you sure that the dll of the environment trigerring the exception correspond to latest version (used locally in Windows 10) ?

Comment: Unfortunately the environment triggering the exception is AWS Lambda (serverless function)--so I can't really open the box there....  I might be able to use some reflection/code to try and look into what dll's are loaded, but I was hoping to not have to do that.

Comment: May you link a .net exe to your AWS Lambda solution ? In this case, you may try to create a public function in a small exe so as to deserialize the XML.

Comment: If you can't reference the exe in the AWD solution, you may dynamically load the exe using "Assembly.LoadFile". Then, call the public function.

Comment: I'm getting the exact issue deploying to AWS Lambda to, i even tried Assembly.Load as suggested (which again, worked fine locally) but same issue still.

Comment: FYI, AWS confirmed it is a bug and they are working on resolving it.

Comment: @Hercules A terrible work around is to use XmlDocument to parse the Xml, and then manually map the xml elements to your objects.  I've done this for now to work around the issue.

Comment: @CamHart thanks, i shall give that a go for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Support just got back to me and confirmed this bug has been fixed.